# Media Import / Export issue in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I had created a custom Content type: "UpComingProducts" in Orchard. This content type had an Image Picker field.

While exporting this Custom Content type: "UpComingProducts", i do select the Images as well in addition to the Metadata and the Data for "UpComingProducts" .

Problem is that on importing, the Content Data is imported successfully but the Images are not getting imported. I checked the "Media" link in Admin Menu and also the Media folder on filesystem, there are NO images there after import.

Please help me here. Why Images are not imported but the rest of custom content is importing properly ?

Comment: I guess the media are exported, as in the table rows, but not the files on the filesystem itself.

Comment: ok. So you mean files on a filesystem and NOT in database should be deployed manually ?

Comment: yeah the Export function exports database records, and you have to manually copy over the filesystem items

Comment: @devqon: Thank you very much for your guidance here. Much appreciated